# Asynctask return null in SDK 23 and below device

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sdk

I'm using Asynctask to pass the parameters of API. The Asynctask executing but the String Response in Asynctask PostExecute giving me a null for a device with SDK 23 and below. But when the device is equal or higher to SDK24(Nougat), it works perfectly and the data are being sent to the API however when the SDK is 23 and lower data are not being sent to API. Does anyone encounter this problem? Please enlighten me what I miss in my code or I do wrong code. Massive thank you.

```
 private class sendToServerOfficial extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

    int statusCodeone;

    String convert_txt_et_username = et_username.getText().toString();
    String convert_txt_content = et_content.getText().toString();

    @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            urlURL = new URL("http://www.testingsite.com/api/sendServer?/ip="+getIPAddress+"&phone_num="+getMobilePhoneNumber+"&user_text="+convert_txt_et_username+"&content_text="+convert_txt_content);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlURL.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","UTF-8");
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            statusCodeone = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCodeone == 200) {
                InputStream it = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(it);
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(read);
                StringBuilder dta = new StringBuilder();
                String chunks;

                while ((chunks = buff.readLine()) != null) {
                    dta.append(chunks);
                }

                buff.close();
                read.close();
                return dta.toString();
            }

        }
        catch (ProtocolException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response + "Form is submitted already" + urlURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        txt_inputURL.setEnabled(true);
        btnClick.setClickable(true);

        txt_inputURL.getText().clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi check the status code when sdk lower 23.  if (statusCodeone == 200) {} else {}

Comment: can you elaborate the answer?

Comment: Add else case for status code check And see what is wrong with the API

Comment: it always gives me a null response in SDK 23 and lower. So i try other way, i use OkHttp. it works now!  I use this references https://trinitytuts.com/get-and-post-request-using-okhttp-in-android-application/